# How is return early concept useful in PHP

Tags: php

I have gone through the best practises in the following link 
https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.bestpractices.php.
I am still not quite clear about the return early concept in PHP . Is it used to reduce the no of else conditions in a PHP function ? When should we ideally use this concept and why is it useful?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the reasons to use return. It can stop function execution when certain condition fails to fulfill its requirements. It could save a few lines, and make your code looks more readable. Imagine executing 100 lines of code when `$a == 2` but return false (error) in `else` statement on line 102.

Comment: you have already answered yourself, it is because no unnecessary code will be run after some precheck can make the function return already.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very crude and oversimplified test but on PHP 7.0.2 `test_func1()` is 33% faster than `test_func2()`:

```
<?php
function test_func1()
{
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){return;}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
}

function test_func2()
{
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    if(1===1){}
    return;
}

$iterations = 1000000;

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$iterations; ++$i)
{
    test_func1();
}
echo (microtime(true)-$start)."\n\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for($i=0; $i<$iterations; ++$i)
{
    test_func2();
}
echo (microtime(true)-$start);
```

Try it yourself at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Like I said, this is oversimplified. Imagine that instead the function makes multiple database calls to compare certain values. If the comparison of the first value renders the calls to subsequent comparisons useless then there is no reason to continue to those comparisons.

Comment: Sry, but i thing on 1 Million iterations the gab is  big!, but with 10000 iterations it can be ignored. And there are many other thigns that can slow down on 1 Mil. iereation like `include` or `sql`. Have a look on speed is good, but with 1 Mil. iter. when yousing the faster `===` (not `==`) a field is reached that is beyond production code and not benchmark relvant, i thing.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Did you decide to 100% ignore both my opening and closing paragraphs?

Comment: As i sayed before, i do imports every day with huge data (from 1GB up to 3GB per script) with amount upto 100GB a day. Moving XML,CSV and other data to Database with complex validation. And `return early concept` is NOT a bottleneck at all. But i decide now to mark this as my last comment here :) PP: `why is it useful`?? `readability`!! And why is PHP7 in your Answer at all??? That was not the question :)999

Answer (score 2):

It's all about CLEAN CODE and **readability**

```
function bad($x,$y,$z){
 if($x){
   if($y){
       if($z){
           /*code work*/
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   } else {
       return null;
   }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function better(){
   if(!$x){
      return null;
   } 
   if(!$y){
       return null;
   }
   if(!$z){
       return null;
   }
   /*code work*/
}

function bestversioninthiscase(){
  if(!$x || !$y || !$z){
      return null;
  } 
  /*code work*/
}
```

..not about about which part of the code gets executed.

Which is more readable here:

```
if($x){
  #code
}
```

or

```
if($x)
{
  #code
}
```

Have fun discussing this topic :)

Answer (score 1):

Short example why it can be usefull

```
//some demo function
function connect_to_ftp($host, $user, $pass){
    //some check if the host is a valid host, just for demonstration
    if (not_a_valid_host($host)) return false;
    //if the host is valid, continue executing, no else required
    make_ftp_connection($host, $user, $pass);
    return true;
}
```