# Codeignitor API Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created this API, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected. The response I am currently receiving is:

> Invalid Input

I've double-checked the input parameters, but I'm still unable to identify the issue. Could you please review the API configuration and let me know if there's anything I might have missed?

Your assistance in resolving this matter is highly appreciated.

```php
public function order_topups() {
    // Retrieve the Authorization header from the request
    $authorizationHeader = $this->input->get_request_header('Authorization');

    if (!empty($authorizationHeader)) {
        // Split the Authorization header into parts
        $headerParts = explode(' ', $authorizationHeader);

        if (count($headerParts) == 2 && strtoupper($headerParts[0]) === 'BEARER') {
            // Extract the token from the header
            $token = $headerParts[1];
            $this->load->library('myjwt');

            // Decode the token
            $verify_token = $this->myjwt->decodeToken($token);

            if ($verify_token !== 0) {
                $this->load->model('order/order_model', 'model');
                $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

                // Extract data from the request payload
                $category_id = isset($data['category_id']) ? $data['category_id'] : null; // Line 654
                $service_id = isset($data['service_id']) ? $data['service_id'] : null;     // Line 655
                $user_id = isset($data['user_id']) ? $data['user_id'] : null;   

                // Retrieve balance information
                $get_balance_by_service_id = $this->model->get_balance_by_service_id($service_id);
                $check_if_user_got_balance = $this->model->check_if_user_got_balance($user_id);

                // Check if balance and service data are available
                if ($get_balance_by_service_id['price'] && $check_if_user_got_balance) {

                    if ($check_if_user_got_balance > $get_balance_by_service_id['price']) {

                        // Set the API token as a header
                       // Set the API token as a header
$headers = [
    'Api-token: 12123123123123123123123123'
];

$url = "https://api.saltiboost.com/client/api/newOrder/$service_id/params?playerID=$user_id";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Log cURL request parameters
error_log("cURL Request Parameters: " . print_r(['service_id' => $service_id, 'user_id' => $user_id], true), 3, "curl.log");


$output = curl_exec($curl);
$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Log HTTP status and response
error_log("HTTP Status: $httpStatus", 3, "curl.log");
error_log("cURL Response: " . print_r($output, true), 3, "curl.log");

if ($output === false) {
    // Log cURL error and handle the error
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    error_log("cURL Error: $error", 3, "curl.log");

    $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'cURL Error');
    http_response_code(500);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);


                        // Check HTTP status
                        if ($httpStatus == 200) {
                            // Continue processing for successful response
                            $decode_data = json_decode($output, true);

                            $new_balance = $check_if_user_got_balance - $get_balance_by_service_id['price'];
                            $update_balance_by_user_id = $this->model->update_balance_by_user_id($_SESSION['uid'], $new_balance);

                            if ($update_balance_by_user_id == 1) {
                                $order_data = array(
                                    "ids" => ids(),
                                    "uid" => $_SESSION['uid'],
                                    "type" => "direct",
                                    "cate_id" => $category_id,
                                    "service_id" => '',
                                    "charge" => $get_balance_by_service_id['price'],
                                    "formal_charge" => $get_balance_by_service_id['old_price'],
                                    "profit" => $get_balance_by_service_id['price'] - $get_balance_by_service_id['old_price'],
                                    'api_token_id' => $decode_data['data']['order_id'],
                                    'media' => 'topup',
                                    "status" => "processing",
                                    "link" => $get_balance_by_service_id['name'],
                                    "created" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                );

                                $this->db->insert("orders", $order_data);

                                $response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Order Placed Successfully');
                                http_response_code(200);
                                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                                echo json_encode($response);
                                exit;
                            } else {
                                $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Balance Not Updated');
                                http_response_code(500);
                                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                                echo json_encode($response);
                                exit;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Log and handle error for unsuccessful response
                            $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid Input');
                            http_response_code(400);
                            header('Content-Type: application/json');
                            echo json_encode($response);
                            exit;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Insufficient Balance');
                        http_response_code(402);
                        header('Content-Type: application/json');
                        echo json_encode($response);
                        exit;
                    }
                } else {
                    $response = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid Input');
                    http_response_code(400);
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($response);
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not providing enough detail. We don't know the parameters you tried, and the response you mentioned is the same for two different cases.

Comment: Additionally, I **strongly recommend** following the concept of [early returns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920539/314056).

Comment: Thanks chritian for the helpful comment, i restyle the code and it was from the 
if (!$get_balance_by_service_id['price'] || !$check_if_user_got_balance) {
        $this->respondWithError('Invalid Input', 400);
    }